# Hibernate Query Tool

Tags: hibernate

I am looking for a way to query a Hibernate database with an external tool (a kind of interactive query editor).  I do not have the source code for the original application.  It is maintained by a separate group.

I attempted using Hibernate Tools from JBoss, but these tools appear to need the source code in order to resolve the mapping.  I also saw a post about using Squirrel and their Hibernate plugin, but the post was not clear on whether it can be used without the java source code.

The application extracts data that is useful, and the developers publish the API.  This seems like a legitimate way to interact with the data.  Perhaps a reporting tool (like Jasper Reports/iReport) will allow ad-hoc queries.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think of is to use Hibernate Tools to reverse engineer he database schema and generate the mapping and the POJO classes for you.

Make the necessary minor adjustments if needed

Go and query

This should work fine enough

Comment: That does the trick.  Not as elegant as I had hoped, but practical.  Thanks.